# marshmallow schema for Joined Table Inheritance (SQLAlchemy + marshmallow)

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, polymorphism, marshmallow

I have a schema similar to

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'employee',
        'polymorphic_on':type
    }
```

I have tables `Engineer` and `Manager` which inherits from Employee

Reference: [SQLAlchemy 1.3 Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/inheritance.html)

I want to define a marshmallow schema

```
from marshmallow import fields, Schema

class EmployeeSchema(Schema):
    """
    Employee Schema
    """
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
    type = <???>
```

Comment: `fields.Str()`?